# Can mutt show the index and body of emails in a horizontal split?

Tags: email, mutt

I'd like to have `mutt` show an index of emails at the same time as the body of the selected email, horizontally next to each other. I [understand](https://github.com/backalor/dotfiles/blob/master/mutt/muttrc) that you can set `mutt` up to show the index of emails at the same time as the body of a message itself in a *vertical* split. For example, in `muttrc`:

```
set pager_index_lines   = 10    # number of index lines to show
set pager_context       = 3     # number of context lines to show
```

This produces a pane showing the email index at the top of the screen, with the body of the selected message in a pane below.

```
  62 r   Jul 22 Sender 1        (783K) Subject 1
  63     Sep 03 Sender 2        (2.9K) Subject 2
  64 r   Sep 17 Sender 3        (2.0K) Subject 3
  65 r   Sep 17 Sender 4        (4.9K) Subject 4
  66 r   Sep 18 Sender 5        (835K) Subject 5
  67     Sep 21 Sender 6        (2.3K) Subject 6
  68     Sep 21 Sender 7        (136K) Subject 7
  69     Sep 24 Sender 8        ( 37K) Subject 8
  70 r   Sep 26 Sender 9        (3.8K) Subject 9
───────────────────[ 71 messages ]───────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Date: Thu, 17 Sep 2015 09:19:22 +0000
From: Sender 3 <foo@bar.com>
To: Me <foo@bar2.com>
Subject: Subject 3
user-agent: foo/bar

Body here. Luctus inceptos tortor parturient bibendum diam. Posuere diam, pharetra
purus nibh posuere, mi feugiat arcu, ve. Dis nostra inceptos, urna, et habitasse a
purus in est ante. Nisi eni lorem. Nonummy non. Leo, dictum venenatis. Mollis.
Dignissim est. Potenti diam et convallis proin aptent ipsum adipiscing dapibus.
```

Is it possible to have the panes horizontally next to each other instead? i.e. as below

```
62 r   Jul 22 Sender 1   (783K) Subject 1 | Date: Thu, 17 Sep 2015 09:19:22 +0000
63     Sep 03 Sender 2   (2.9K) Subject 2 | From: Sender 3 <foo@bar.com>
64 r   Sep 17 Sender 3   (2.0K) Subject 3 | To: Me <foo@bar2.com>
65 r   Sep 17 Sender 4   (4.9K) Subject 4 | Subject: Subject 3
66 r   Sep 18 Sender 5   (835K) Subject 5 | user-agent: foo/bar
67     Sep 21 Sender 6   (2.3K) Subject 6 |
68     Sep 21 Sender 7   (136K) Subject 7 | Body here. Luctus inceptos tortor parturient bibendum diam. Posuere diam, pharetra
69     Sep 24 Sender 8   ( 37K) Subject 8 | purus nibh posuere, mi feugiat arcu, ve. Dis nostra inceptos, urna, et habitasse a
70 r   Sep 26 Sender 9   (3.8K) Subject 9 | purus in est ante. Nisi eni lorem. Nonummy non. Leo, dictum venenatis. Mollis.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, mutt itself cannot do this and no [patches](http://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/PatchList) currently exist for that, either.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to answer this with prrof, since it's likely a negative answer. However, this question has been open long enough that I'll accept and upvote (for the link). Thanks.

Comment: The neomutt devs have actually [discussed it](https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt/issues/1250) after seeing this question, and concluded that it was nice to have, but that they didn't have time to implement it.